# mysql delete and leave one that used in other table

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables:

Table 1

```
ID NOMOR_LOGO
1 ABC
2 ABC
3 ABC
4 DEF
7 GHI
8 GHI
```

Table 2

```
ID ID_NOMOR_LOGO
1 1
2 5
3 6
```

1. table1.ID = table2.ID_NOMOR_LOGO
2. delete duplicate data in table 1 and leave only data which is used in table 2
3. if duplicate data has no associate with table 2, delete all AND leave 1
   data (any data, maybe with lowest ID)
4. if no duplicate in table1.NOMOR_LOGO, don't delete this data

The result should be like this

```
ID NOMOR_LOGO
1 ABC
4 DEF
7 GHI
```

Thank you

Comment: So you need to delete duplicate entries in table 1 and those delete operatios should cascade to table 2?

Comment: something like that

Comment: "something like that", what does that mean? Either it does or it doesn't, we can't guess what you want so tell us what table 2 has to do with this? I see no correlation between tables 1 and 2.

Comment: Does table 2 have a foreign key constraint and delete on cascade ?

Comment: Does every duplicate data in `Table 1` corresponding row in `Table 2` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze not necessarily

Comment: @Faiz - In this case you need delete all duplicate rows from  Table 1?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I have update the information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE NOTE, this assumes that:

1) relation between tables is: `Table 1.ID = Table 2.ID_NOMOR_LOGO`

2) `Table 1.ID` is unique

3) If duplicate data in `Table 1` not have corresponding row in `Table 2`, all duplicate rows from `Table 1` will deleted.

```
   DELETE t1 FROM Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
   Table1 t2 
   WHERE
   t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.NOMOR_LOGO = t2.NOMOR_LOGO
   AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ID_NOMOR_LOGO = t1.ID);
```

Comment: assumes 1 and 2 is correct. But in number 3, If duplicate data in Table 1 not have corresponding row in Table 2, all duplicate rows from Table 1 will deleted AND leave 1 only (any data is ok. Maybe the lowest ID).

Answer (score 0):

Join first table with itself to identify duplicates and join second table to not delete rows present there.

```
DELETE a 
FROM table1 a
JOIN table1 b ON  a.nomor_logo = b.nomor_logo AND a.id > b.id
JOIN table2 C ON a.id != c.id_nomor_logo;
```